# Password field is blank after filling registration form laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have registration form in that their are basics field when i try to insert data to database password column gets blank value ,when i tried to insert my record from php artisan tinker command its working means password column gets its value

following is my code

RegisterController.php

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'user_firstname' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'user_lastname' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'user_phone' => 'required|numeric|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'username' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',

    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    //dd($data);
    return User::create([
        'user_firstname' => $data['user_firstname'],
        'user_lastname' => $data['user_lastname'],
        'user_phone' => $data['user_phone'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

}
```

}

```
<div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I am just creating user object and using laravel elequant to insert row into database previously its been working but now all the database columns has the value entered in forms except password field, dont know whats the problem please help me

Comment: check the value which is returned by `Hash::make($data['password'])`

Comment: when i removed has::make its not saving its plain password value

Comment: is there any file involved apart from controller and model

Comment: Have you added password field in $fillable array in the Model.

Comment: its working now its missing from fillable array only present in hidden array thanks alot abhilash